# I want to expose naked xml/json on VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to expose self generated XML (or JSON) from VisualForce. However I cannot find the way to override the parent pages on an apex:page component so I am getting the whole menu, bars and all he extra html around.

But I only want to serve the selfgenedated xml. Basically I want to do this:

http://salesforceserverXX.com/apex/page ---->

content

Is that possible?

Comment: I added an xml sample after ----> But I guess stackoverflow escaped it for security issues.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's possible. Below VF code output JSON string. Please note the showhedear and contentType parameter. ControllerClass is the apexclass hosting "processRequest" method which generates a JSON string "requestReponse"

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerClass"
    contentType="text/javascript"
    showHeader="false"
    cache="true"
    expires="1"
    action="{!processRequest}">{!requestResponse}</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out [this discussion thread](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Generating-an-XML-from-VF-page-using-ContentType/td-p/131288).